# User flow with on-demand service platform

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-centered-design, selling-ux

Product: XYZ On-demand service provider (example cleaner)

Context: User has to select at least 4 service providers to increase his chances of getting a service provider he has selected on the platform.

User flow: John wants his house to be cleaned. He opens an app, selects his location, selects the time and then he sees a list of cleaners in his area who are registered with XYZ. He selects a cleaner with good reviews and high ratings and pays the deposit.

Cleaner flow: Cleaner Alpha receives a notification and decides not to take the job because he is a freelancer and XYZ cannot lock him into the obligation of taking the job.

User frustration: John is informed by XYZ that Alpha is not available and he has to choose another cleaner from the list again after going through the same user flow.

XYZ solution: In order to increase John's chances of getting the cleaner he selected, now XYZ encourages John to select at least 4 cleaners in the flow. For example, Alpha, Beta, Gama, Zero. The reason behind this is if Alpha and Beta reject the job, there is still a chance that Gama and Zero will accept it and someone will go to Johns house to clean the house.

Question: I understand there is a fundamental flaw in the service design with the product. Now as a UX designer, what is the most human way to solve John's frustration?

A. Pre-select 4 cleaners and tell John why the system is doing it for him.
B. Disable the next action to go to the payment unless he selects at least 4 cleaners.
C. Any other way to solve this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Munishwar

Very intelligent analysis by the way.

I think It would be good UX to pre select multiple cleaners and explain to John why he is doing that (though I feel 4 is a dime too much).

Also, the multiple selection can be made optional such that he could select the cleaner he wants first and then have the option to select maybe two more cleaners just in case the first choice isn't available at the instance.
That way John is in no way compelled to pick cleaners he would not have picked in the first place.